# nose-knows generating an empty .knows file

Tags: python, nose

I'm trying to get the nose-knows plugin work https://github.com/eventbrite/nose-knows, but for some reason it's creating an empty .knows file. I installed it with `pip install nose-knows` and I run nose with

```
$ nosetests -sxw tests --with-knows --knows-dir=package/ --knows-out
```

I tried several different values for the `knows-dir` parameter:
* .
* ../
* tests/
* And no specifying it at all

The directory layout is as follows:

```
-- project/
   -- tests/
   -- package/
```

Where `package` is the directory that contains the actual package, the unit tests in `tests/` are running as expected, as file `tests/.knows` is created, but it's empty. The unit tests are taking twice as long with knows enabled, so apparently it is doing *something*.

Anyway, I suspect it's a bad case of pebkac, so how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In our Jenkins build we have it set to the name of the base directory, which in your case is "project". The documentation should be updated with this info, but it needs to be a directory name, not a path to the directory.